# Creating histograms for mulitple IDs in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataset like:

```
    Count          ID      size 
0   25             0001    1     
1   4              0001    2    
2   9              0001    3    
3   13             0001    4     
4   19             0001    5    
...          
8   11             0003    10           
9   10             0003    12              
10  7              0003    14              
11  15             0003    16
```

The objective is to plot a histogram for each unique ID, with the size on the x-axis as the boxes and the count on the y-axis is count. I've tried using the following code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

for d in df.groupby(df['ID']):
    plt.hist(d[1][['size','Count']])
    plt.show()
```

However, this does not give me the desired result as this is the way to plot a normal graph but not a histogram. Unfortunately, I have not been able to figure out how to tackle this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might want barplots, not histplots.
You can use [`seaborn.catplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html):

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.catplot(data=df, x='size', y='Count', col='ID', kind='bar')
```

output:
[image: seaborn catplot]